# Migrating from Waffle

Tags: solidity, hardhat, chai, waffle

sorry for a newbie question. I have a file from my study with the following code:

```
const { expect, assert } = require("chai");
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");
const { impersonateFundErc20 } = require("../utils/utilities");

const {
  abi,
} = require("../artifacts/contracts/interfaces/IERC20.sol/IERC20.json");

const provider = waffle.provider;
```

Everything worked first, but after installing new Hardhat I saw a message about migrating from Waffle to Hardhat Chai Matchers. I've done everything from hardhat documentation. But without Waffle I'm receiving an error:

*ReferenceError: waffle is not defined*

If I install waffle back hardhat tells that there is a conflict. Is there any way to use this Chai Matchers or I need to install everything as it was 2 months ago with an older Hardhat and Waffles?
Thanks and sorry again)

Comment: Pro tip: you can just use my [Hardhat-based template](https://github.com/paulrberg/solidity-template) to get the Hardhat Chat Matchers automatically configured for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your line

```
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");
```

to

```
const { ethers, waffle } = require("hardhat");
```

and try again

[Link to doc](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/other-guides/waffle-testing)

Answer (score 0):

instead of waffle.provider;
try ethers.provider;

then run the test. it worked for me.